# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core” | cloud_firestore, Flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I am having some issues in the pod, see below

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Core` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
          GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "gRPC-Core":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
          gRPC-C++ (~> 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
            gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
              gRPC-Core (= 1.14.0)

    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
          gRPC-ProtoRPC (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
            gRPC-ProtoRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
              gRPC (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
                gRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
                  gRPC-Core (= 1.14.1)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.5/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:123:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:781:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:779:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:88:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone X.

Comment: Same problem here, no solution....

Comment: I didn’t find any fix for the above said issue, but downgrading the flutter to old which dart 1 and cloud_firestore 7.4 will avoid these problems. But pop ups some other.. like this one ‘ atal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ‘

Answer (score 230, accepted):

My setup: VS Code, Flutter

If you don't have `Podfile.lock` file and `pod update` doesn't help, try this:

1. Go to `ios/Pods/Local Podspecs` directory in your project
2. Check every `json` file to find highest required ios version. Mine was `"ios": "10.0"` in some of them
3. Go back to `ios/` directory
4. Open `Podfile` file
5. Uncomment `# platform :ios, '9.0'` and replace `9.0` with version from 2. step, for example `10.0`.

   - `# platform :ios, '9.0'` > `platform :ios, '10.0'`
6. Run `pod install` and the error should be gone

Comment: Yeah I did this too, worked. I think the flutterfire team needs to fix their dang dependencies

Comment: agree @ShazamoMorebucks this is very cumbersome, I believe tech lead's comments on YouTube regarding Flutter have a lot of merit. I don't see Flutter as a long term solution as its fundamentally broken with so many issues that are never fixed.

Comment: It's important not forgetting to **uncomment** the `# platform :ios, '9.0'` line as it is commented by default and one may not see that immediately.

Comment: This works for me, but I just need to uncomment the platform on podfile one, and increase the minimum platform to 11.0 no need to go into each local podspecs.

Comment: To get the version numbers out of all the json files, run this command:
find ios/Pods/Local\ Podspecs/ -name \\*.json -exec jq -r '.platforms.ios' {} \; | sort -un

Comment: CMD+Shift+F and write `platforms": {` and scroll between all targets in your dir

Comment: Solved it for me too. Interestingly, this was working fine on another computer but I only hit this issue after moving the project to a new computer.

Comment: Only the `pod update` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 127):

```
pod update
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I get this error: Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod

Comment: This will update all your pods though, which you might not want. I think Random Code Money's solution is better. Basically clear the Cocoapod cache from the project and reinstall.

Comment: Just to clarify. If using Android Studio --> Press Terminal --> cd ios --> pod update

Comment: for newbies (me): if using vs code's terminal, change directory to 'ios' (cd ios) and then 'pod update'

Comment: what about m2 user?

Comment: This worked  = arch -x86_64 pod update

Answer (score 47):

On mac M1 (in ios folder), try `arch -x86_64 pod update`. Worked for me

Comment: Platform : ios , '14.0' and arch -x86_64 pod update  <-  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

I got a similar error:

> Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

---

### What did not work for me:

As per the other answers, I went to the `Podfile` & updated:

- from: `# platform :ios, '9.0'`
- to: `platform :ios, '13.0'`

Then tried `flutter run` again but this time it was stuck at:

> `Running Xcode build...`.

The wait was unnatural & my patience grew thin so I discarded this change & looked for another solution.

---

### Finally, What worked for me:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `flutter run`

No need to modify `Podfile` to specify a minimum ios target

Comment: Based on your answer, I tried the `flutter clean` version first. It did nothing. So I tried the `Podfile` version, and yes, the wait was unbearable!... But I went and had supper, and when I came back, I found that after 4,000 and something seconds, the project had built! 

Comment: Oh... and the next time I built the project, it took 70 seconds. 

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar issue. Set Project, Target and Podfile to iOS 12 and get failure.

**Here's my Podfile:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'all_pods' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator'
    pod 'Atributika'
    pod 'AXPhotoViewer'
    pod 'Cache'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'GTMNSStringHTMLAdditions'
    pod 'KVLoading'
    pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'SDCAlertView'
    pod 'SideMenuSwift'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
    pod 'UIImageViewAlignedSwift'

target 'Test Poject' do
#    all_pods
end

end
```

**First deintegrate to be sure**

pod deintegrate

**Run forced repo update**

pod install --repo-update

```
Updating local specs repositories
$ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XYZ/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
  remote: Counting objects: 9, done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.        
  remote: Total 9 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     8b2bcbd42ee..f72b5a3a02a  master     -> origin/master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XYZ/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XYZ/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at f72b5a3a02a [Add] DSJSONSchemaValidation 2.0.4

CocoaPods 1.6.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.6.0.beta.1

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Core` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
      FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
        GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: ***Update*** I got this to work by adding this line to my Podfile:     pod 'Firebase', '~> 5.7'

Answer (score 8):

if you are running on Mac M1 (apple silicone chip) , try run this command :

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 7):

For Mac with M1 chip (2022) :

What did the trick :

- Change `platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '11.0'` in your `Podfile` file in `<project>/ios/`
- Then update as follow : `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update` in your terminal (`<project>/ios/`)

All the dependencies and pods will be installed !

Enjoy !

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but this helped me.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '>= 0'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '>= 0'
```

It will update both FirebaseCore and FirebaseCrashlytics to the latest versions

Answer (score 4):

just on pod file UnComment

`# platform :ios, '9.0'`

and replease it with
`platform :ios, '10.0'`

then delete Podfile.lock and reInstall your app

Comment: Yes! it worked. It saved lots of time for me

Comment: I had to realize couple of steps more. Here is the answer which I'm referring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69249116/12051755

Answer (score 3):

These 3 steps worked for me.

1. Upgrade cocoapods to latest version:

   `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Delete `/Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file
3. Run `pod repo update`

Answer (score 3):

I had to update in Podfile.
`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.0.0'`.
to new version.
`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.9.1'`

Answer (score 3):

For Those who have an Apple Mac with M1 chip :

-> try this sequence hope you see... pods are installing.

1. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
2. `arch -x86_64 pod install` or  `arch -x86_64 pod update`  or `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 2):

This issue is coming from following line added to pod file. Alway make sure the tag is updated to the correct [version here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/ios/firebase_sdk_version.rb). Default version in the firebase documents are at times aged and should be updated to current version by checking it.

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.11.0'
```

[Read more on this from here.](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks#readme)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue:
[image]

To fix the problem, I opened the Podfile. Then

1. I uncommented `platform: ios, '8.0'` and replaced it by `platform :ios, '10.0'`, as mentioned in the other answers.
2. I replaced the following code:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.3.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

With this code:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```

3. In Terminal, I ran the following command in the `ios` folder.

```
$ pod install
```

Everything went well. I didn't see any issue but a lot of green logs which basically are related to `Installing FirebaseX...` and at the end I got this message:

```
Pod installation complete! There are 8 dependencies from the Podfile and 24 total pods installed.
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem (Intelli J)

1. Check in IOS flutter folder Podfile.lock is generated.
2. Run 'flutter doctor -v' to identify version of the Flutter,Dart,Xcode and CocoaPods version.
3. Incase cocoa pods are not found, follow install commands.

   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   brew uninstall cocoapods

   sudo gem install cocoapods
   pod setup
4. In Podfile - Uncommented platform: ios, '9.0' and replaced it by platform :ios, '10.0'.
5. Run the build

   Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
   Running pod install...
   Running Xcode build...
   Xcode build done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZ7G.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem just by updating the platform version from the profile:

Go to **iOS / Podfile**:

> Open Podfile

Uncomment the platform version:

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'  //Uncomment this line
```

To this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'  //Uncomment & make version '9.0' to '10.0'
```

**Boom !!! Solve the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with firebase Admob and my problem was that I was using both admob_flutter and firebase_admob packages. Once I removed the admob_flutter package from pubspec.yaml and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:

1. go to file %project%/ios/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios/firebase_sdk_version.rb
2. change this `def firebase_sdk_version!() '8.7.0' end` for `def firebase_sdk_version!() '8.5.0' end`
3. run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems at the same time here. Cant update cocoa pods because of firebase dep. and can't update because of minimum deployment target.

Do:

- pod reintegrate
- uncomment the second line in pod file and elevate te platform: iOS to 11.0
- pod update

that's the trick

Comment: Could you plz be more specific! Where do I find this "pod file"?

Comment: Sure. You can find it in Folder: IOS/podfile.

This is a autogenerated file by the system with the dependencies you put in pubspec.yaml. Thats why sometimes we need to adjust it

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was:

1. Bump NodeJS version from `16.0.0` to `16.5.1`. To do so quickly, I'm using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md).
2. Install the Firebase CLI running `npm install -g firebase-tools`. [Firebase CLI docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-npm). My version is `firebase-tools@11.0.1`.
   *If you have more packages, use `npm list -g` to list them, and then install them in the new NodeJS version.*
3. Run `firebase login` locally access your Firebase Console.
4. [In your Flutter app's folder root] Run `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get`.
5. Add Firebase Core ([pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/install)) to your app and others Firebase's libraries.
6. Run `flutterfire configure` to set up the connection between your app and Firebase.
7. Initialize Firebase: [steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase)
8. Run your app.

*PS. According to https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/versions, the min Dart is `2.16`. Maybe you need to change it on your `pubspec.yaml`*

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to delete .symlinks, Podfile.lock, Podfile and start the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Navigate to your ios folder (inside your flutter project).
2. Then navigate to Pods/Local Podspecs/
3. Then run this command: `grep -rn "ios" *json`.
4. Remember the higher ios version.
5. Navigate to PodFile in the ios directory of your project and make sure that
   this line appears: `platform :ios, '<the higher ios version from step 3>'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove iOS/podlock
2. pod install

Answer (score 0):

Just go to project's `ios` directory and run following command:

> `arch -x86_64 pod update`

Note: It has been worked for me on ***MacOS M1, 2020 (apple silicone chip)***.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no solution, it may mean that you are working in a closed environment. And your company's inner jfrog pods may not contain that version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to remove `pub-cache` folder in addition to `podfile.lock` which was mentioned before.

In `finder` app use the `GO` menu to go home.

Next, press `SHIFT` + `COMMAND`+ `.` (full stop key). This is to show hidden folders.

Finally, delete `.pub-cache` folder.

After this run the original command again: `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score -2):

```
#To your Podfile, add the Firebase pods that you want to use in your app.

platform :ios, ‘10.0’

# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# For Analytics without IDFA collection capability, use this pod instead
# pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```