# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, podspec, podfile

I've updated my flutter package to the last versions and now IOS doesn't work anymore.

When I try to update the pods it shows this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Firestore (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.0.0)

cloud_functions (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_functions/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Functions (~> 5.18) was resolved to 5.18.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.18.0)
```

Here my pubspec.yaml (Firebase related):

```yaml
#firebase
firebase_core: "^0.4.0"
firebase_auth: "^0.11.0"
firebase_analytics: "^3.0.0"  
cloud_firestore: "^0.11.0+1"
cloud_functions: "^0.3.0"
firebase_storage: "^3.0.0"
firebase_messaging: "^5.0.1"
```

I've made various steps to try to fix:

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios

pod install
pod update
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
```

I've set platform :ios, '12.1' in Podfile and in Xcode as build target but nothing come back to works.

Here my podfile:

```rb
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know the flutter yaml, but  the `0.11.0+1` looks suspicious since FirebaseFirestore is asking for Firebase 6.x and FirebaseFunctions is asking for Firebase 5.x

Comment: I put my answer under another question in case the accepted answer didn't halp. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047809/513413

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Try calling `pod repo update`

if the issue is not fixed

delete the Podfile.lock in the root directory, after that  run `pod install`

Comment: `rm -rf Podfile.lock` then `pod install` worked for me.

Comment: For M1 macs: alias pod="arch -x86_64 pod"

Comment: Also if you are developing a react-native application using yarn run `yarn add all`

Comment: flutter 3 not working for me

Comment: `pod install --repo-update`  can also be used

Comment: `rm -rf Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update`

Thanks @Mohhamed Nabil

Comment: pod repo update worked for me

Comment: pod repo update worked for me!

Comment: pod repo update worked for me

Answer (score 166):

Edit the minimum ios version in the podfile then run pod install.

Changing `platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '10.0'` then running `pod install` fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked perfect, when I have changed it in Xcode under "Runner" -> "Runner" -> "Info" -> "iOS Deployment Target" to version >= 10.0.0

Comment: This worked out for me as well. Removed `Podfile.lock`, then ran `pod repo update`  and `pod install`.

Answer (score 115):

For M1 Mac Users

1. Go to `ios/Pods/Local Podspecs` directory in your project
2. Check every `json` file to find highest required iOS version. Mine was `"ios": "10.0"` in some of them
3. Go back to `ios/ directory`
4. Open `Podfile` file
5. Uncomment `# platform :ios, '9.0'` and replace `9.0` with version from step 2. *- for example* `10.0`.

**then here comes the M1 specific part**

6. Run `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
7. Run `arch -x86_64 pod repo update`
8. Run `arch -x86_64 pod install` error should be gone
9. If using Flutter `cd -`  back to your root directory - open iOS Simulator & run `flutter run`

*If not working you might need to run `flutter pub add firebase_core`to add firebase_core to your `pubspec.yaml` file Before Step 1*

---

If still not working try this BONUS STEPS :

- Trying to Run directly from Xcode ? First Run `flutter build ios` in your Flutter project -> then Run in Xcode
- Still not working `cd iOS` run `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`
- Still not working ? Search Keychain Access in Spotlight -> open -> Right-click on login -> Unlock (you will lock back when build succeeds)
- Still not working ? [image: Xcode Runner Info Screenshot] make sure your Runner Info Configs look like this

Answer (score 39):

Just do a `pod update` and then `pod install`. This worked for me.

Comment: `pod update` upgrades the dependency packages to the latest version. Probably not what's wanted by the OP or others coming to this thread.

Answer (score 28):

1. Execute `flutter clean`
2. Go to `ios/` folder, edit `Podfile` and choose the platorm and version you want to launch. For example for platform **ios** and version **12.0** :

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

3. Execute `pod update`
4. Execute `pod install` (it can take a some minutes to download dependencies)
5. Execute `flutter run`

Answer (score 27):

If you are using an M1 mac.

Delete podfile.lock by running

```
arch -x86_64 rm -rf Podfile.lock
```

and then update pods by running

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked for me because I'm m1 user.

Comment: If you are having to run any pod installs inside Rosetta then your machine is not set up correctly.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me, and the simplest!

Comment: You can run the rm command without intel architecture.

Comment: What are the implications of running this first command without being on a mac m1? I am on a regular mac intel and erroneously ran that. I think I may have really messed something up...

Answer (score 17):

## ***For M1 Mac***,

### It is easiest and fastest to find the answer in the last part.

move to folder ios:

```
cd ios
```

> Method 1:

Open your terminal and run

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

restart IDE or Editor

> Method 2:

*Note: Try only if **Method 1** will not work*

Now time to install pod for **M1 Mac**:

```
 sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
 arch -x86_64 pod repo update
 arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Now **99%** chance installation error should be gone

Now only for the 1% chance that you are still getting errors:

open your ios Runner XCode project and follow the image instructions.

**Change your Excludeed Architectures from Architectures for Target**

```
form i386 to arm64 i386 (Note: space is important)
```

[image]

Now come back to your root directory and run

```
 flutter run
```

> Also, Restart your editor.

> Advance Note:

Getting this error multiple times and copy-pasting each time fixes it.
Therefore, I am here to offer a better way to accomplish this with the help of method 2:

Copy below the Written code

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

You will need to create a script file in your IOS Folder, let's call it **pod_install.sh**
Should you ever encounter the same problem again, you will only need to run one command.

```
sh pod_install.sh
```

from your ios folder

now enter the password of your mac

now tea ☕ time

> Don't forget to Restart your editor.

Comment: `arch -x86_64 pod repo update` this command works for me... 
after that, i am able to install pod on M1 by `arch -x86_64 pod install` this command...

Comment: On M2 Mac this command `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` gives me error "arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable".

Answer (score 14):

[image]

To use the "firebase_core" dependency with version ^1.0.3, the "iOS Deployment Target" has to be not less than "10.0"

Comment: HERO, took two days to figure out the M1 settings, although they were working on M1 but for some reason it stoped. And pod install or update never worked again until those methods. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

**=== 2023, April UPDATE ===**

As of 2023, April, you have to do this:

Edit `iod/Podfile` and edit/modify or uncomment this line :

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Save the file and execute this command in ios directory:

```
rm -rf Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this same issue when trying to add Firebase Analytics to my projct. I kept running pod update in the terminal, but I couldn't successfully get to FirebaseCore (6.0.0) until I made sure that all flutter packages in the pubspec.yaml file were on the latest version.

1) I got rid of the package that was causing the error. For me, it was Firebase Analytics because I had just added that to my project.

2) I went through all of the firebase packages and made sure I had the most recent version in my pubspec.yaml. Here they are:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0
firebase_database: ^3.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.11.0
firebase_storage: ^3.0.0
```

3) Navigate to ios folder and run pod update

4) Add Firebase Analytics package (or whatever you are interested in adding) to pubspec.yaml.

5) Run packages get

6) Run pod install in terminal

Answer (score 8):

March 2021

`cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0`

```
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod repo update
```

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution worked for me (Suggested by the IDE itself)

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Run the command in terminal IOs folder

Answer (score 5):

## In React Native

```
cd ios

rm -rf Podfile.lock

pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

`pod update` then `pod install`. This worked for my side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Comment: after that delete pods folder, .symlinks folder and podfile.lock file and then pod install.

Answer (score 4):

At first delete podfile.lock file from your ios folder

then goto your ios folder from terminal

```
cd ios
```

now type in terminal

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

or

```
pod install
pod repo update
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me when i added the highest ios version dependency from the symlinks/plugins in the Podfile platform :ios, '11.0'

Answer (score 3):

As of 28 April 2021, what worked for me (after days of struggle):

In AppDelegate.swift (flutter-project/ios/Runner), add these 2 lines:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

In Terminal:

```
pod repo update 

flutter build ios
```

Then run your project in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Go back to the `ios` folder and open the Podfile then change platform as below `platform :ios, '10.0'`. After that click the `run` button from your Editor.

Answer (score 2):

If after doing the:

Try calling pod repo update

if the issue is not fixed

delete the Podfile.lock in the root directory, after that run pod install

That @mohhamed mentioned, it's still not working, please do the following since this has to do directly with the versions that your packages have on the pods.xcodeproj file a quick way you can set this up is the following:

`run flutter clean` then run `flutter pub get`.

once you do that open you xcode project, doesn't matter if it was opened before, right clic on IOS and clic on the open in xcode.

while it's indexing go back to your console and do `flutter run`.

when you get to have the error again. head into xcode and look for this issue under the issues tab.

[issues tab on xcode with validate project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dO7d.png)

as you can see we are being recommended by xcode to update to the recommended setting on our Pods.xcodeproj file. once we clic on it, we will see the following screen.

[Build recommended settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0R5W.png)

at last clic in perform changes and it will updated the dependencies of the file.

after this you are all set, you can do `flutter run` and continue to do the coding.

now please have in mind that if you run `flutter clean` again, you will incur into this error again and will have to re do the previous steps.

Answer (score 1):

This migration guide for react-native-firebase could be useful for your case:

https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6#removing-v5-from-javascript

I uninstalled version 5 and installed version 6, but it seems there was some extra work to do to get rid of older versions of firebase.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete Podfile
2. pod init
3. pod install

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.

1. delete the Podfile.lock in the ios directory
2. after run arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been so annoying. But this is how I solved it.
1- First of all, I updated the firebase packages.

```
   firebase_core: 1.10.0
   firebase_auth: 3.4.1
```

2- I went into the Android studio terminal and wrote it.

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod repo update
```

3- in the ios folder
I deleted the .symlinks folder

4- Finally,I also wrote in Terminal

```
pod install
```

If it still fails, change the firebase updates from step 1 and repeat the other steps.

Answer (score 1):

My podfile had this line commented `platform :ios, '11.0'` and set to 11 i uncommented and changed to 14

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052116/4833705) and do 2 things

1- In my Podfile I had `platform :ios, '13.0'`, I had to switch it to `platform :ios, '10.0'`

2- I had to remove my entire podfile and reinstall it but this time for the Firebase/Database pod I used `pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 7.0.0'`

My podfile looks like this now:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyApp' do
use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyApp

pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 7.0.0'

// other pods ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue.

1. I guess you add new firebase package and then issue appear.
2. remove last added packages
3. run flutter clean
4. delete podfile.lock
5. Ensure all firebase packages use updated version
6. run flutter pub get
7. go cd ios/
8. run pod install
   Then fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to pubspec.yaml and make sure the flutter fire packages are all compatible together. My issue was because firebase_remote_config version was slightly newer than the cloud firestore and consecutively caused the error when I ran Pod update.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that worked for me, this was being caused because I was using an older version of a Firebase dependency. So **upgrading all dependencies** and then using flutter pub get and flutter run worked for me

Answer (score 0):

## Context

- Mac Silicon chip M1
- Flutter 3.13.1
- Cocoapods 1.11. All the releases here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases

## Solution

1. Go to `ios` folder, `cd ios`.
2. Run `arch -x86_64 pod repo update`. We use `arhc -x86_64` to support Silicon chip architecture.
3. Upgrade to the latest Cocoapods version: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
4. Be sure you have `ffi` package: `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
5. Install your Flutter app's ios packages: `arch -x86_64 pod install`.
6. Done! Run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding pods manually in podfile

```
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in cloud_functions plugins.
They have 5.18 version of Firebase.
For fix it you must change manually the file cloud_functions.podspec in the ios folder of the plugin while their doesn't finally fix.

Change it

> s.dependency 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.18'

to

> s.dependency 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 6.0'

After that still remaing an error regarding some missed dependencies of Firebase functions files.

I add directly in the pod this line:

> pod 'Firebase/Functions'

I know that all this is an workaround but works in this way for me.

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly said that you have a compatibility issue in your cocopod file which may caused when you update the flutter dependencies.You can resolve the issue by reconfiguring the pod files: run these commands.

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get
>
> flutter upgrade
>
> cd ios
>
> pod cache clean --all
>
> Pod clean
>
> pod deintegrate
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
>
> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
>
> arch -x86_64 pod repo update
>
> arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have a similar line in `ios/Podfile`:

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
```

If you do, try commenting it out with a `#` at the beginning of the line, or removing it.

When adding Firestore, I followed the advice from the instructions and added this line in order to use a pre-compiled framework and decrease build time on iOS. Removing this line immediately solved this issue for me and `pod install` completed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 - Try calling pod repo update

Step 2 - delete the Podfile.lock

step 3 - cd ios

step 4 - run pod install

step 5 - cd ..

step 6 - flutter build ios