# Firebase iOS - Multiple errors while archiving in Xcode 13.4 or Xcode 14.1(iOS 15 or iOS 16)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Getting multiple errors while archiving the project but app build/run fine. Tried many solutions related to cleaning derived data, deintegrate/integrate/install pods, pod clean etc.(['GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809424/googleutilities-gulurlsessiondataresponse-h-file-not-found)) (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2233)

[image]

Podfile :

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    
    install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
    
    target 'Test' do
      platform :ios, '14.3'
      use_frameworks!
      inhibit_all_warnings!
    
      pod 'SwiftLint'
      pod 'KeychainAccess'
      pod 'AEXML'
      pod 'GooglePlaces'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
      pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
      pod 'CocoaDebug', :configurations => ['Debug']
      pod 'atlantis-proxyman'
    
      target 'TestTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
      end
    end
```

Podfile.lock

```
    PODS:
      - AEXML (4.6.1)
      - atlantis-proxyman (1.20.0)
      - CocoaDebug (1.7.2)
      - Firebase/Analytics (10.2.0):
        - Firebase/Core
      - Firebase/Core (10.2.0):
        - Firebase/CoreOnly
        - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 10.2.0)
      - Firebase/CoreOnly (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCore (= 10.2.0)
      - Firebase/Crashlytics (10.2.0):
        - Firebase/CoreOnly
        - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 10.2.0)
      - Firebase/RemoteConfig (10.2.0):
        - Firebase/CoreOnly
        - FirebaseRemoteConfig (~> 10.2.0)
      - FirebaseABTesting (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
      - FirebaseAnalytics (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 10.2.0)
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
        - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
      - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
        - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 10.2.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
      - FirebaseCore (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCoreInternal (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.8)
      - FirebaseCoreInternal (10.2.0):
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
      - FirebaseCrashlytics (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
        - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
        - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
      - FirebaseInstallations (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.8)
        - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
      - FirebaseRemoteConfig (10.2.0):
        - FirebaseABTesting (~> 10.0)
        - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
        - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
      - GoogleAppMeasurement (10.2.0):
        - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 10.2.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
      - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (10.2.0):
        - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (= 10.2.0)
        - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
      - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (10.2.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.8)
        - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.8)
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
      - GoogleDataTransport (9.2.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
        - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
        - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
      - GooglePlaces (7.2.0)
      - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger
        - GoogleUtilities/Network
      - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.10.0):
        - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
      - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Environment
      - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger
      - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger
        - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
        - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
      - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.10.0)"
      - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger
      - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.10.0):
        - GoogleUtilities/Logger
      - KeychainAccess (4.2.2)
      - nanopb (2.30909.0):
        - nanopb/decode (= 2.30909.0)
        - nanopb/encode (= 2.30909.0)
      - nanopb/decode (2.30909.0)
      - nanopb/encode (2.30909.0)
      - PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
      - SwiftLint (0.50.1)
    
    DEPENDENCIES:
      - AEXML
      - atlantis-proxyman
      - CocoaDebug
      - Firebase/Analytics
      - Firebase/Crashlytics
      - Firebase/RemoteConfig
      - GooglePlaces
      - KeychainAccess
      - SwiftLint
    
    SPEC REPOS:
      https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git:
        - AEXML
        - atlantis-proxyman
        - CocoaDebug
        - Firebase
        - FirebaseABTesting
        - FirebaseAnalytics
        - FirebaseCore
        - FirebaseCoreInternal
        - FirebaseCrashlytics
        - FirebaseInstallations
        - FirebaseRemoteConfig
        - GoogleAppMeasurement
        - GoogleDataTransport
        - GooglePlaces
        - GoogleUtilities
        - KeychainAccess
        - nanopb
        - PromisesObjC
        - SwiftLint
    
    SPEC CHECKSUMS:
      AEXML: 1e255ecc6597212f97a7454a69ebd3ede64ac1cf
      atlantis-proxyman: c3ca06216fbb5cf87a83de3911f955dcb1615048
      CocoaDebug: 61cf93ada6ce8f3407507dc01f9b874d91ac1d5c
      Firebase: a3ea7eba4382afd83808376edb99acdaff078dcf
      FirebaseABTesting: 22840e1573ea2fbb519f5a2f1c93be7232508358
      FirebaseAnalytics: 24a15e58e505abcedc3017b6f7c206fbfa964580
      FirebaseCore: 813838072b797b64f529f3c2ee35e696e5641dd1
      FirebaseCoreInternal: 091bde13e47bb1c5e9fe397634f3593dc390430f
      FirebaseCrashlytics: df7406152189d48346deafb716806d7bd9ebb573
      FirebaseInstallations: 004915af170935e3a583faefd5f8bc851afc220f
      FirebaseRemoteConfig: 5bdeadd64a042dad0f6a38fee7e017818240c3d2
      GoogleAppMeasurement: 3bc3a6484b7bb20dd8489242c4dd3c92a3e5107b
      GoogleDataTransport: 1c8145da7117bd68bbbed00cf304edb6a24de00f
      GooglePlaces: 590dea495d69431454ea92217033c3184995165d
      GoogleUtilities: bad72cb363809015b1f7f19beb1f1cd23c589f95
      KeychainAccess: c0c4f7f38f6fc7bbe58f5702e25f7bd2f65abf51
      nanopb: b552cce312b6c8484180ef47159bc0f65a1f0431
      PromisesObjC: ab77feca74fa2823e7af4249b8326368e61014cb
      SwiftLint: 6b0cf1f4d619808dbc16e4fab064ce6fc79f090b
    
    PODFILE CHECKSUM: 330733d16ffa7f8b7749843d82f340e9c137b794
    
    COCOAPODS: 1.11.3
```

Comment: user:556617  - I went through where you answered and tried those solutions but it's not working. Could you please help here?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in Google's [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#cocoapods), the pods have been updated to have a different format. For example, to install the Firebase Analytics library, it would no longer be `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`, but rather `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'`.

Comment: I already tried using pod 'FirebaseAnalytics' but it didn't fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the problem is from Configuration.
When build/run: use Debug configuration
When Archive: use Release-Prod configuration.
There is a difference between them, I guess.

Comment: While Archiving, already using release-Prod configuration.

Comment: Did you use the same Target for Release-Prod and Debug configuration?
Let check the difference between 2 configurations!