# Flutter Firebase Pubspec.yaml Update-- Getting [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":

Tags: flutter, upgrade

After updating my pubspect yaml versions from

```
firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
firebase_core: ^1.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
```

to

```
firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
firebase_core: ^1.1.0
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.11.0)


    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
       You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.
```

After running 'pod init' inside iOS folder, I'm getting

```
[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
```

and after running 'pod install' within the iOS folder also,

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

However. The Podfile DOES EXIST.
[Please refer to the image attached][1]

Also, my Flutter Doctor is showing no errors.

Thanks, and all best,
-A.V.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR2kx.png

Comment: Hi! I fixed this issue by simply deleting the Podfile (inside the iOs package) and then running a mixture of the following commands INSIDE THE IOS packagge-- simply select this folder and type into the terminal the following:  ' pod install ' , ' pod repo update' , and 'pod update' .                       This enabled my Pod to download the versions compatible with the FirebaseCore/ only packages.

Answer (score 0):

the answer that worked for me on a similar issue is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70029467/3120387

1. Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
2. Delete Podfile.lock (YourPoject/ios/Podfile.lock)
3. Delete Project.Workspace file.
4. Run pod install --repo-update (Make sure your cd into the iOS directory of the flutter app)
5. Run flutter clean
6. Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run

Answer (score 0):

The usual call for this error usually boils down to try calling `pod repo update`.

If this doesn't work, delete the ***Podfile.lock*** in the root directory and run `pod install` after.

> For M1 Mac users, try the following:
>
> 1. Go to ***ios/Pods/Local*** Podspecs directory in your project
> 2. Check every json file to find highest required iOS version. Mine was `"ios": "10.0"` in some of them
> 3. Go back to ***ios/ directory***
> 4. Open ***Podfile*** file
> 5. Uncomment `# platform :ios, '9.0'` and replace `9.0` with version from step 2. - for example `10.0`.
> 6. Run `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
> 7. Run `arch -x86_64 pod repo update`
> 8. Run `arch -x86_64 pod install error` should be gone
> 9. If using Flutter `cd -` back to your root directory - open iOS Simulator & run `flutter run`

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042932/8342742) from SO for more solutions.