# Firebase app check on iOS get crash on build

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

Every think were working very well until I added package `firebase_app_check: ^0.0.3`

The app gets crashes on the building project to run on iOS, on Android it works very well.

Andoird app can connect to firebase but, iOS cant do that becouse the request does not authnticated.

**Flutter :2.5.2**

**Verbose**

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A firebase_app_check
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - cloud_functions


 Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_functions` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_functions/ios`


 Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json


[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/AppCheck":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_app_check (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_app_check/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
          Firebase/AppCheck (= 8.9.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/AppCheck (= 8.9.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.




.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `platform :ios, '11.0'` to the Podfile.

AppCheck [requires iOS 11](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.1/Firebase.podspec.json#L172).

Answer (score 3):

I think, your CocoaPods setup is going to break. because firebaseAppcheck version issue. You are going to have to manually delete any local copies of the Specs repository and re-clone the new version of the Specs repository. You can do that with the following below commands:

It can be solved by executing the following commands in the terminal.

```
1. Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
2. Delete Podfile.lock (YourPoject/ios/Podfile.lock)
3. Delete Project.Workspace file.
3. Run pod install --repo-update (Make sure your cd into the iOS directory of the flutter app)
4. Run flutter clean
5. Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run
```

if the above step not working for your project. You can also try this:

```
 1. change the higher minimum deployment target (at least 11). 
 2. Just Follow the above steps.
```