# cocoapods error in flutter project m1 macbook

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I’m in trouble with my m1 macbook pro.

When I run my flutter app which contains firebase core(1.5.0 ver), I got errors at cocoapods.

I did so many approaches to solve this problem but none of them are not working...

here is my error message (flutter run)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             805ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.5.0)

    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.5.0)`.

    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update



Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

and when I run ‘pod repo update’

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

/usr/local/bin/pod repo update

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.10.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.5.1 (20G80)
       Xcode : 12.5.1 (12E507)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

### Error

LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): could not use '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' because it is not a compatible arch - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135:in `block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+could+not+use+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+because+it+is+not+a+compatible+arch+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - pod install has bug
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10723 [closed] [14 comments]
   4 days ago
when I run ‘pod install’ at my ios folder
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.5.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.5.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I tried
`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
and
`arch -x86_64 pod install`
but not working…
is there anyone who has a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my error by

`cd ios`

Run `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

Run `arch -x86_64 pod repo update`

Run `arch -x86_64 pod install`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68406454/16696093

Comment: yeah you probably only needed the repo update bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check you active support version update it to the latest or to the one that matches your pods version!