# I get an error when I run pod install in Flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I always get this error when I run the 'pod install' command;

[image]

Here's the list of ways I've tried to fix it;

- I deleted all pod files and reinstalled
- pod install --repo-update
- pod update
- pod clean
- sudo gem update cocoapods --pre
- pod deintegrate
- flutter clean

I would appreciate it if you could help me fix this error. Thanks

Comment: Did you delete podfile.lock too? If you didn't delete it and after that use commands in order:  

flutter clean,
flutter pub get,
pod install

Comment: Yes, I did that, it doesn't work. I always get the same error

Comment: Can you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055142/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-coreonly)

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I have done all the solutions in this link. Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What is your deployment target in Podfile? I had some similar issues when it was commented out or it was too low. I use Firebase with 12.1 as iOS deployment target.

Comment: It was 11, I changed it to 12 and reinstalled the pods but still getting this error

Comment: @MuhammedYesilmen I also have a loop in `Podfile` that sets `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 12.1 in every build configuration, have you tried something like that?