# Flutter CocoaPods could not find compatible version: Cache and BetterPlayer

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I tried to install the pod for Flutter on iOS with CocoaPods but got following error when I started:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible version for pod "Cache":
  In Podfile:
    better_player (from ´.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios´) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Cache (-> 6.0.0)

Specs satisfying the ´Cache (-> 6.0.0)´ dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055142/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-coreonly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please Try this steps :

**if you have intel chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0' or higher version
4. go to ios folder through terminal and do 'pod repo update'
5. 'pod update' or 'pod install'

**if you have M1 chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0' or higher version
4. go to ios folder through terminal and do 'arch -x86_64 pod repo update'
5. 'arch -x86_64 pod update' or 'arch -x86_64 pod install'