# Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ObjectBox"

Tags: ios, flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm using OjbectBox for the first time in my Flutter project. After I wrote the basic code to read and right user data, I'm getting this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ObjectBox":
  In Podfile:
    objectbox_flutter_libs (from `.symlinks/plugins/objectbox_flutter_libs/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      ObjectBox (= 1.6.0)

    objectbox_sync_flutter_libs (from `.symlinks/plugins/objectbox_sync_flutter_libs/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      ObjectBox (= 1.6.0-sync)
```

I did what's recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443888/flutter-cocoapodss-specs-repository-is-too-out-of-date-to-satisfy-dependencies#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20/ios,application%3A%20flutter%20run) (first one) but I'm getting the same error when I try to update with `pod install --repo-update`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please check this answer. May be It will be your answer [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336969/flutter-cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-version-cache-and-betterplayer/69341182#69341182)

Comment: @TusharMoradiya Thanks but it didn't work for me. There is something wrong with ObjectBox library itself. I better go them.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this is by doing 3 things:

1- Deleting the sync library `objectbox_sync_flutter_libs` entirely (I don't necessarily want to sync between devices. I just thought it would be cool to use it in the future but it's not a must). 2- Changing the version of `objectbox_flutter_libs` to 'any'. 3- Using a version for `objectbox_generator` that's similar to ObjectBox version, which is 1.2.0 in my case.

There was no need for any `flutter clean` or deleting `podfile_lock` and re-getting or so, at least for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to have `platform :ios, '11.0'` top of the Podfile, along with the other setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal run

`pod repo update`