# @react-native-firebase pod version conflict for Firebase/CoreOnly

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react-native project with these dependencies (all are the latest available):

```
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/config": "^0.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^14.5.1",
```

But when I go to `pod install`, I get:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 14.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.12.1)

    RNFBConfig (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/config`) was resolved to 0.1.5, which depends on
      Firebase/RemoteConfig (~> 6.5.0) was resolved to 6.5.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.5.0)
```

I do not understand why config has a different version to all the others and how the latest versions of a project are conflicting.

I have tried the following to fix this:
`rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock`
`pod repo remove trunk`
`pod install`
`pod update`
`pod install --repo-update`

My ios/Podfile does not contain explicit pods for Firebase.

Usually these commands tend to fix problems like this. But not this time. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried this? 

Edit the minimum ios version in the podfile then run pod install.

Changing platform :ios, '9.0' to platform :ios, '10.0' then running pod install

Comment: try the other solutions from here. [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055142/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-coreonly)

Comment: The iOS version is already 11 in my file. None of the answers in that question work and lots of the answers are mistakenly attributing M1 chip.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by deleting the `./ios/Podfile.lock` and run again `pod install --repo-update` command.

Answer (score 2):

react-native-firebase maintainer here!

The 'config' package was wrapping the firebase "Remote Config" SDK packages, so that name was not used in the final release of react-native-firebase - we used "remote-config" in the end, but the alpha releases with the wrong name were still up on npmjs.com.

I just deprecated all versions of that package on npmjs.com so users should get a warning if they try to install it - no one should use that package. If you use the 'remote-config' one, you'll be all set I think

Comment: Thanks for doing that and for the explanation! Now nobody else will get confused.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that react native update a new architecture

- Open the file *Podfile* and add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` inside your targets
- Disable the `:flipper_configuration` line
- Put `$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true`
  at the top of podfile

Then run

```
pod install --repo-update
```

For Mac M1

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Hope this useful to someone

Comment: We should never use Rosetta for pods, if you need to do so then something is wrong with your machine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@react-native-firebase/config` appears unrelated to the `@react-native-firebase` project, hence the different latest version and pod conflicts. I had to use `@react-native-firebase/remote-config` instead, as found in the documentation https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase