# Circular Flutter error running pod repo update followed by flutter run

Tags: flutter, macos, cocoapods

On a mac m2 running `flutter build macos` fails with the error

```
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update
```

Running pod repo update does not fix the problem. I have tried rm -rf ios/Pods, flutter clear and flutter pub get but nothing seems to work. I have tried all the solutions I can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055142/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-coreonly?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) but still the same error. This project was created on ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to run it on my mac mini m2. It has FlutterFire deps but I have run the update command in the cli.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

Navigate to the /ios folder within your project.
Delete the `Podfile.lock` file located at Your Project/ios/Podfile.lock.

Open the command prompt and execute the command `pod repo remove trunk`.
This will remove the pod repository.

To completely remove the pod, run the appropriate command based on your Mac chip:

For Intel chip users:
Run `pod install --repo-update`.
Make sure you are in the iOS directory of your Flutter app (use cd command to navigate).

For M1 or M2 chip users which would be your case:
If not already installed, run `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` in a regular terminal to install ffi.

Then execute `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`.

If you encounter an error regarding the compatibility of the cloud_firestore pod, do the following:

Open the Podfile and locate the line that starts with platform :ios.

Uncomment the line and set the minimum deployment target to '12.0' (or a higher version if needed).

It should look like: `platform :ios, '12.0'`.
Run `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update` again.

This time, the installation should work fine.

Clean the Flutter project by running flutter clean.
Finally, execute flutter run to run your project.

Comment: at `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ff` I get error `arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable`. This is a mac mini m2.

Comment: Maybe try this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture

Comment: Nothing in the above link worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with

```
macos % sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

then

```
pod repo update

pod install
```