# firebase_crashlytics was resolved to 2.2.1, which depends on Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.6.0)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, crashlytics

I'm getting an error trying to build a flutter app with crashlytics
(but somehow builds successfully on codemagic)
I did

- follow the [official steps](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/#b-ios)
- try to use this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410300/16087862)
  without success

these are my logs

```
╰─$ flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in <my app>_time_reporting...               804ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,179ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      - Flutter
      - connectivity_plus
      - device_info
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_crashlytics
      - flutter_barcode_scanner
      - image_picker
      - package_info
      - path_provider

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`
    firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_barcode_scanner` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_7_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.3.0)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`) was resolved to 2.2.1, which depends on
          Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.6.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.3.0), Firebase/Crashlytics (= 8.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Smart quotes were detected and ignored in your Podfile. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

- this is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047809/16087862
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
end

# or pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’
# for Analytics without IDFA collection capability

# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    #target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    #  config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    #end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047809/16087862
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

- this is my pubspec.yaml

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.13.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  beamer: ^0.14.1
  connectivity_plus: ^1.1.0
  device_info: ^2.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.17.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^0.14.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  shimmer: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  stub: ^0.3.0  
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: images/icon.png

flutter_native_splash:
  color: '#ECEFF1'
  image: images/splash.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/english.png
    - images/splash.png
```

- my flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale en-EE)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/francesco/fvm/versions/stable
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (10 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/francesco/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 7D1B0B46-6D39-40A9-8792-8853C86AB930 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have tried look at other proposed solutions,
but I see that mostly is recommended to bump the ios version
(I have done that already)

any suggestion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```sh
rm pubspec.lock && \                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
flutter clean && \
cd ios && \
pod cache clean --all && \
cd .. && \
flutter pub get && \
cd ios && \
pod update && \
cd ..
```

then `flutter run`

fixes the problem

Comment: This solved my problem but since I have M1, instead of "pod update" I had to use "arch -x86_64 pod update"