# Flutter / iOS : Could not determine bundle id

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-ios

In my Flutter project, I try to compile and run my app. It works fine on Android but for some reason, out of nowhere, I now have the following error when I run my app on iOS:

```
2022-06-11 16:21:02.274 ios-deploy[42320:338779] [ !! ] [ ERROR] Could not determine bundle id.
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008030-001C085222DA803E.
```

So here is what I checked:

- `Info.plist`: there is `Bundle identifier` with the value `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`
- In `TARGETS > Runner > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Bundle Identifier`, I have the expected value (my package name)
- In `TARGETS > Runner > General > Bundle Identifier`, the value is set as expected (my package name)
- In `TARGETS > Runner > Build Settings > Packaging > Info.plist File`, I have the correct location: `Runner/Info.plist`
- I tried `flutter clean`, Invalidate caches & Restart on Android Studio, Clean Build Folder on Xcode
- I tried even more cleaning as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083485/3527024)

And here is my `Info.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>$(APP_DISPLAY_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Wezeejay</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>ENVIRONNEMENT</key>
    <string>$(ENVIRONNEMENT)</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>NSCameraUsageDescription</string>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But I still have that error just when the app is about to launch, which I have no idea where it comes from since it was working perfectly just two days ago.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open the workspace file in xcode. Select runner from the side panel and select general tab. You should be able to see the bundle id. Add bundle id in this section

[image: preview]

EDIT
/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

remove all contents of this folder and from Xcode go to product, clean build folder and then build again

[image: Preview]

Change use Release for command line builds to debug and build once. Then switch it back to release

Comment: Thanks, but it's already set. As I said, it worked fine a couple days before, but not anymore, for some reason.

Comment: updated my answer please check

Comment: Go to finder. On top you will see a go then select goto folder. Enter ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData   this will take you to the derived data folder.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know `Library` was hidden

Comment: Still not working, I still have the same error.....

Comment: Edited answer again

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error. This is beyond me...

Comment: Please try to build on a real device

Comment: That's what I do already

Comment: In the iOS folder delete .symlinks folder, Pods folder and Podfile.lock. Then run pod install from terminal. Then try to build it

Comment: Well, guess what? Still the same error! But thanks again for your patience and your help!

Comment: please include your info.plist file

Comment: Just updated my post

Comment: info.plist looks good. By any chance do you use Firebase if yes do you have googleservices.plist file included?

Comment: Yes I have Firebase and the googleservices.plist files included, and it has always worked perfectly

Comment: In android studio or VS code find `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =`  and see if any of the results have no value or a different value

Comment: I see nothing wrong so far, and again, it was working fine a few days ago and I haven't modified anything.

Comment: Finally managed to make it work as posted above (or below). I still have no idea why it happened in the first place....

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to make it work by:

- updating Mac OS
- unstalling and installing the latest version of Xcode