# Flutter: unable to run flutter run or pod install

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

My application was working and running and I tried adding a new dependency and now my app won't build. I'm trying to figure out what the issue may be but can't seem to figure it out. I tried following the solution listed out here: [How to solve "error running pod install" in flutter on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135078/how-to-solve-error-running-pod-install-in-flutter-on-mac) but it crashes when I run pod install and gives me the following:

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Firestore (= 8.9.0)

  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 9.6.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore (= 8.9.0), Firebase/Firestore (= 9.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I then tried to follow the solution listed here: [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core” | cloud_firestore, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398435/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-core-cloud-fir) and it doesn't seem to be the source of my problem because my Local Podspec with the highest ios platform requirement is `"ios": "11.0"` but in my Podfile I am running `platform :ios, '11.2'`.

If it's of any use, this is what I am getting when running `flutter run`

```
Running pod install...                                             557ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A path_provider_foundation
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - flutter_ringtone_player

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '9.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_ringtone_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_ringtone_player/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
      update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Firestore (= 8.9.0)

      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
          Firebase/Firestore (= 9.6.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore (= 8.9.0), Firebase/Firestore (= 9.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment
    target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

Edit: in response to the comments that have been left. When I run `pod repo update` I get the following error:

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command


/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod repo update


### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack


   CocoaPods : 1.11.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
       Xcode : 13.4.1 (13F100)
         Git : git version 2.33.1
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/


### Plugins


cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0


### Podfile

   ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.9.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


### Error


LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:144:in `block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:142:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:142:in `block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:140:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:140:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'


――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64e%27%29%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28no+such+file%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

and when trying to remove the Podfile.lock file and running `pod install` I get the exact same error I got earlier.

Comment: did you try `pod repo update`?

Comment: Remove Podfile.lock and then run pod install again.

Comment: when trying `pod repo update` I get a `LoadError`

Comment: when removing the Podfile.lock and running `pod install` I get the same error: `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore"...`

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last two days looking to solve this error, and I just found the solution that worked for me, on a MacBook M1, before this I tried everything, and this solved it

1- In the Podfile add this line of code:`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.3.0'`
(this last number must be the version of your firebase, in your case 9.6.0)

2- in the ios folder run: `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Here is a pic of the Podf

[Podfile Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Zyi.png)

After that all the pods were installed in the folder and I was able to run the simulator from VSC

I hope this helps